# Adding Formula to a cell using macro

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

```
Dim dflrow As Integer

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ElecTM").Range("I1048576").Select

    dflrow = Selection.End(xlUp).Row

'        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ElecTM").Range("AG" & dflrow & ":" & "AJ" & dflrow).Select

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ElecTM").Range("AG6").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(Year(I6),"w",WeekNum(I6))"

    Selection.FillDown
```

Here I am getting an error saying syntax error on fifth line. I have tried'.value' instead of '.Formula'. But that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing double quotes in `"w"`

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ElecTM").Range("AG6").Formula = _
"=CONCATENATE(Year(I6),""w"",WeekNum(I6))"
```

You have to pad the `"` with extra `"` if using between `""`

**EDIT**: When in doubt, record a macro ;)

Comment: Thanks...,it worked..could you tell me why we have to put two double quotes in macro when we only have to put one pair double quotes in cell in excel??...

Comment: so that `"` is considered as a string :)

Comment: When i use followin code it says "Run time Error 1004.Application defined or object defied error.

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ElecTM").Range("AI6").Formula = "=IF(I6=(TODAY()+1),""Y"","")"

    Selection.FillDown

Comment: Try `"=IF(I6=(TODAY()+1),""Y"",)"` Like I mentioned in my post above... Record a macro when in doubt...

Answer (score 0):

w should be in double quotation

`ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ElecTM").Range("AG6").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(Year(I6),""w"",WeekNum(I6))"`

Comment: Thanks...,it worked..could you tell me why we have to put two double quotes in macro when we only have to put one pair double quotes in cell in excel??...

Comment: Refer this [link **Concatenation & Quotes (#quotes)**](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~tplacek/courses/3600/Strings%20and%20Manipulations.htm)

Comment: [Link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa212167(v=office.11).aspx)